# Retained fragments not retained with saved instance state in Android activity

Tags: android, pdf, android-fragments

I'm building a PDF-reader app targeting Android 4.1 and later. I have an activity that maintains two separate view fragments and a retained 'headless' fragment (which manages the pdf document state). Because I dont want to have to re-read the PDF document each time a configuration change occurs, the document-state fragment utilizes setRetainInstance:

```
public class PDFDocumentFragment extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setRetainInstance(true);
```

All of these are support fragments and hence the owning activity is actually a FragmentActivity. Until recently this was working well, retaining the state in PDFDocumentFragment across configuration changes but I just added some saved instance state to my activity by overriding onSaveInstanceState in the activity :

```
public class ReaderControllerActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    public static final String STATE_KEY_READER_LAYOUT = "readerLayout";

    private ReaderLayout mCurrentLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        savedInstanceState.putString(STATE_KEY_READER_LAYOUT, mCurrentLayout.toString());
    }
```

ReaderLayout is just an enum indicating the type of view - text or original PDF being shown.

PROBLEM:

After adding the saved instance state to the activity as above, I no longer get my original retained fragment back following a configuration change ie this code in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    PDFDocumentFragment pdfFragment = (PDFDocumentFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PDF_DOC_FRAGMENT_TAG);

        if( pdfFragment == null )
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()  
                .add(PDFDocumentFragment.newInstance(), PDF_DOC_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .commit();
        }
```

will add an entirely new PDFDocumentFragment when onResume is called following a configuration change - which obviously it should not do as PDFDocumentFragment should have been retained.

Is there some sort of conflict between saved instance state for activities and retained fragments? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you find `frag`, but check if `pdfFragment` is null. is it correct?

Comment: My mistake on pasting - I am retrieving and then checking both pdfFragment. Have edited the question to reflect this (and problem remains),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be because you don't call `super.onSavedInstanceState` after saving your activity's instance;
Original `onSavedInstanceState` of the `Activity` class saves state of `Fragment`s:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBundle(WINDOW_HIERARCHY_TAG, mWindow.saveHierarchyState());
    Parcelable p = mFragments.saveAllState();
    if (p != null) {
        outState.putParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG, p);
    }
    getApplication().dispatchActivitySaveInstanceState(this, outState);
}
```

Comment: Yes.. you are right. That solves the problem - thank you. I'm just kind of wondering now the relationship between saving local activity instance state has to do with retaining fragments.

Comment: because Fragment class doesn't provide onSave(Restore)InstanceState. retaining state is controlled with a single flag (`setRetainInstance`) and maintained by the underlying activity